# How to convert anonymous function to a regular one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, anonymous-function

Total JS noob here.  I have the following line that implements the jQuery Slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wheelLeft").slider({ 
                 orientation: 'vertical', value: 37, 
                 min: -100, max: 100, 
                 slide: function (event, ui) { $("#lblInfo").text("left"); } });
    });
</script>
```

Basically on the `slide` event, the `#lblInfo` gets its text set to `left`.  This works fine.  However, I'd like to convert the inline anonymous function that handles the slide event into a regular function.

Can someone help out?

Comment: @Ivo JS is a new thing for me (last time I used it was in 1999).  I wasn't even sure that anonymous functions were called that in JavaScript land.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how ppl assume high rep = knowledge of all topics and languages...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function handleSlide(event, ui) { 
    $("#lblInfo").text("left"); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wheelLeft").slider({ 
             orientation: 'vertical', value: 37, 
             min: -100, max: 100, 
             slide: handleSlide
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(event, ui) {

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        myfunc(event, ui)
    });
</script>
```

would do it. It's obviously not an ideal solution as it still uses the anonymous but should solve any issues you have where you need to manipulate the function manually

Answer (score 2):

Just define a named function:

```
function doSlide(event, ui)
{
    $("#lblInfo").text("left");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wheelLeft").slider({
        orientation: 'vertical', value: 37, 
        min: -100, max: 100, 
        slide: doSlide
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function myFunction() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this may not be what you're looking for. This is actually useful to imitate `arguments.callee()` in ES5 strict mode.